# Почему хук не хочет срабатывать?

Tags: wordpress

Я создал дополнительно поле в комментариях с помощью хука comment_form_logged_in_after

```
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'extend_comment_custom_fields' );
function extend_comment_custom_fields() {
  echo '
 <select  name="test">
    <option value="t1">t1</option>
    <option value="t2">t2</option>
    <option value="t3">t3</option>
</select>
';
}
```

и пытаюсь записать результат с помощью хука comment_post

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_extend_comment_meta_data', 10, 1 );
function save_extend_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ){
echo '<h3>sdf</h3>';
update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'meta_test', $_POST['test']);
}
```

Но я не знаю почему но он не работает

echo нечего не выводит а поле meta_test не обновляется.
я даже специально указал точное id и value

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_extend_comment_meta_data', 10, 1 );
function save_extend_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ){
update_comment_meta( 34, 'meta_test', 'fof');
}
```

но нечего не поменялось 
Может кто сказать что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

Оказало что я засунул хук comment_post не в тот файл темы изо чего он и не срабатывал
Надо было его вставить в function.php вместо comments.php